# How to resolve CosmosDB Connector in Logic App giving unauthorized Error?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-logic-apps, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

[image: Error Snapshot]

The connection details are correct.

> I am able to successfully run a cosmos db **"Query documents"**
>   connector in the same logic app

while the **"Get a document"** connector is failing.

I used the same id in both connectors though to fetch the document!
[image: This one works though!]

Comment: can't reproduce your issue, the same process did works for me. Are you sure your connectors point same cosmos db account? please check again.

Comment: you configured connector manually(fill the account name and account key) or select account directly?

Comment: We can't just take your word about the connection details being correct. Uncensor your post and use the read-only key so we can help you.

Comment: I just used the drop-down (in the connector) to select the database and collection! Is there any setting to be enabled on the cosmos-db database?
Connectors that work - Query a document || Create or update document
Connectors giving unauthorized - Get a document || Replaace a document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the mistake!

Unfortunately, The document id I was trying to fetch contained **double pipe ('||')** Eg('123456||abc')

It was the reason I was getting the Unauthorized error!

The surprising thing is when I am able to insert/Query the documents using the same id, why can't I even fetch with the same id (containing double pipe)?

Anyways, updated the logic to change the id's and working fine now!